# Discrete Probability Distribution in Java

Tags: java, math, probability

I have a set of integers each of which has a probability assigned, derived from earlier experiments, e.g.:

```
0 = 0.5
1 = 0.2
2 = 0.3
```

Complying with the specifications of a probability distribution, these weights sum up to 1.0.
I am now looking for an efficient way to sample one of the values while taking the given probabilities into account, e.g. (pseude-code):

```
Distribution distribution = new DiscreteDistribution(new double[]{0.5, 0.3, 0.2});
distribution.sample();
```

This should result in 0 half of the time according to the given numbers. However, do not assume any patterns or regularities among these.

I've been using [Apache Commons Math](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/distribution.html) for my previous experiments, but it does not seem to provide a solution for this scenario, neither does [Colt](https://dst.lbl.gov/ACSSoftware/colt/).

I wonder whether this is  because I've missed an easy solution. A naive implemententation seems more or less straight-forward, but doing this efficiently is rather involved. That is why I am looking for an established implementation.

Comment: Can you get away with something as trivial as if(Math.rand() > 0.5) {// result is 0}?

Comment: This is called a Discrete Distribution. There's some good background at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution#Discrete_probability_distribution

Comment: "doing this efficiently is rather involved". In what way? What kind(s) of efficiency/ies are you seeking?

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom The complexity I was afraid of was that this may really involve high-dimensional data structures. I am aware that this is a discrete distribution, but I've been looking for a specific implementation. In the meantime, I've found that Apache Commons Maths actually seems to provide one, named `EnumeratedDistribution` / `EnumeratedIntegerDistribution`.

Comment: Since you've found the "established implementation" that your question calls for, wouldn't it make sense to provide your own answer to the question? That, IMO, would be the most sensible/useful thing to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very simple generic solution would be:

```
class Distribution<T>{
    List<Double> probs = new ArrayList<>();
    List<T> events = new ArrayList<>();
    double sumProb;
    Random rand = new Random();

    Distribution(Map<T,Double> probs){
        for(T event : probs.keySet()){
            sumProb += probs.get(event);
            events.add(event);
            this.probs.add(probs.get(event));
        }
    }

    public T sample(){
        T value;
        double prob = rand.nextDouble()*sumProb;
        int i;
        for(i=0; prob>0; i++){
            prob-= probs.get(i);
        }
        return events.get(i-1);
    }
}
```

Feel free to change it, as you need it, e.g. with adding other constructors. Of course here is a lot of stuff to improve, starting with the efficiency, but it is something you can reuse later a lot.

Comment: Despite finally having come across the `EnumeratedIntegerDistribution` in Apache Commons Maths, I think this provides the most complete solution, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Given the simplicity of the *quantile* function and the triviality of a manual implementation, I don't see any harm in writing this out explicitly.

Once you've drawn your random number `r` in [0, 1), use

```
if (r <= 0.5/*micro-optimisation: most likely case first*/){
    return 0;
} else if (r <= 0.8/*then the next most likely case*/){
    return 2;
} else {
    return 1;
}
```

Perhaps things get a little more fancy for more than 3 numbers, consider building up a table to represent the quantile function in such cases, at the expense of some degradation in performance.

(It would be difficult to beat my solution in terms of speed, in the worst case you have a couple of branches - and you're helping a *branch predictor* in the nicest way you possibly can, and the random number drawing will be where the performance bottleneck is).

Answer (score 4):

Calling `Random.nextDouble()` is a fairly expensive operation. You are better off using `Random.nextInt(n)` in this case

```
int num = rand.nextInt(10);
return num <= 5 ? 0 : num <= 8 ? 1 : 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I think this may become very valuable. However, this should rather be a comment on the other solutions, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Carsten he's actually provided a complete solution. It's a very compact answer, but it's an answer, it's simple, it works, and it performs well.

Comment: True, Unfortunately, I can mark only one answer as correct. @ctst's seems more general which is why I've picked his one.

Comment: @Carsten feel free to up vote. Even if you can't decide, I would reward to person with the lowest rep points ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is perhaps a more dynamic approach supporting any probability distribution specified as an array of doubles:

```java
public static int getRandomOutcome(double[] probaDist) {
    List<Double> sortedProbaDist = new ArrayList<>(probaDist.length);
    for (double d : probaDist) { sortedProbaDist.add(d); }

    Collections.sort(sortedProbaDist);

    double randomNumber = Math.random();
    
    double acc = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<sortedProbaDist.size(); i++) {
        acc += sortedProbaDist.get(i);
        if (randomNumber < acc) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return probaDist.length;
}
```

Note that the method does not check whether the probabilities sum up to (near) 1.

Comment: An optimization could be to iterate in descending order, to remove the need for the accumulator.